# Aggregation of time series model

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, aggregation

> Consider the ARIMA(1,1,1) model $$(1-0.5B)(1-B)y_t=(1+0.8B)a_t$$ where
>   $a_t\sim WN(0,\sigma_a^2)$ and a second independent process given by
>   $$z_t=(1+0.5B)b_t$$ where $b_t\sim WN(0,\sigma_b^2)$ with $\sigma_a^2=\sigma_b^2=\sigma^2$.Give the model
>   for the aggregated model $$w_t=y_t+z_t$$ and discuss situations in
>   which this type of aggregation occurs.

Let
$$\Phi_Y(B)=(1-0.5B)(1-B)=1-1.5B+0.5B^2$$
$$\Phi_Z(B)=1$$
$$\Theta_Y(B)=1+0.8B$$
$$\Theta_Z(B)=1+0.5B$$
So
$$\Phi_Y(B)\Phi_Z(B)w_t=\Phi_Y(B)\Phi_Z(B)y_t+\Phi_Y(B)\Phi_Z(B)z_t$$
$$\Phi_Y(B)\Phi_Y(B)w_t=\Phi_Z(B)(1+0.8B)a_t+\Phi_Y(B)(1+0.5B)b_t$$

Then in the left side I have
$$(1-1.5B+0.5B^2)w_t$$
that is an AR(2) and in the right side I have
$$Q_t=a_t+0.8a_{t-1}+b_t-2b_{t-1}+1.25b_{t-2}-0.25b_{t-3}$$
In this case, since $Q_t$ is a sum of independent gaussian white noises $Q_t$ is also white noise right?
Then
$$(1-1.5B+0.5B^2)w_t=Q_t$$
is an AR(2) process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For self-studying it could be useful to read the general aggregation of time series as in Granger and Morris: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345178

Technically you applied the formulas correctly. Still check the second line after "So", since $\Phi_Z(B) = 1$ and $\Phi_Y(B)$ is missing (corrected it in your post).

The left hand side will be driven by exactly the same polynomial of the ARIMA process $Y_t$ $\Rightarrow$ ARI(1,1) rather than AR(2). While $Q_t$ is a MA(3) part of the right hand side. True that Gaussian, but with some colored dependence $\Rightarrow$ is not a white noise, strictly speaking. So, what you get as an answer then?

And, as far as I see, you still missing a discussion in your answer. So, think about any practical situation, when to a process with a stochastic trend some extra disturbance is added.